# Ayuda con MVC Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio, mvc, entity-framework

Este es mi controlador:

```
public ActionResult Index()
  {
    IEnumerable<ent.RRHH_SEDE> listar = db.TraerTodo();
    Enumerable<mod.RRHH_SEDEModel> entidad = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ent.RRHH_SEDE>, IEnumerable<mod.RRHH_SEDEModel>>(listar);
    return View(entidad);
  }
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
<td nowrap>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UBICACION)
</td>
<td nowrap>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RRHH_MUNICIPIO.COD_DEPARTAMENTO)  ///NO ME MUESTRA DATOS
</td>
```

Mi modelo

```
public class RRHH_SEDEModel
{

    public short COD_SEDE { get; set; }
    public string NOMBRE { get; set; }
    public string UBICACION { get; set; }              
   public virtual RRHH_AREA_SEDE RRHH_AREA_SEDE { get; set; }
    public virtual RRHH_MUNICIPIO RRHH_MUNICIPIO { get; set; }
    public virtual SEG_ESTADO SEG_ESTADO { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Pero no me muestra datos en la vista, solo me muestra los propios de la clase `sede`.

`Departamento` y `Municipio` me salen vacíos.

Comment: Intenta primero colocando un breakpoint en el return de la accion y revisa si los valores estan cargados en entidad, asi podras ver si es un problema del controlador o de la vista.

Comment: gracias lo probare.